# Rule-Based Symbology Label disappers from Layers Panel

Tags: qgis, layers, symbology

Attached is a screenshot of my project.  As you can see from the 'Layer Styling' panel I have labels for my 'sensor.udl' symbols.  However, they are only visible on the 'Layers' panel when I re-start QGIS or when I double click the layer.  They are visible, then disappear when I click somewhere else. Is this a bug?

[image: QGIS Screenshot showing missing labels]

Comment: What QGIS version?

Comment: 3.14 on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Comment: Not sure if a "bug" or not. At least unwanted behavior. I come accross this issue every now and then when using geometry generator or rules.

Answer (score 2):

I guess they have not disappeared: I think it is (just) an "alignment" trouble.
I have something almost like this...
If you expand the layer's panel on the right, you will probably see both your symbols and their names (actually, a little part of your symbols are visible in your screenshot), but in a "centered" way in a too large column, not a "stack on the left" way.

This was just a diagnosis help, I'm looking for the "how to fix-it" too!